# htaccess mod_rewrite HTTP 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This particular code works on one server, but not the other. The working one has Apache2, the other Apache1. How can I make it work on both?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # SEO translation
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?.*-p-([0-9]+)$ page.php?page_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
  RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*) $1?%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

Input URL alternatives:

- www.domain.com/some-fancy-title-p-10
- www.domain.com/en/some-fancy-title-p-10
- www.domain.com/sv/some-fancy-title-p-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears ?: is not valid regexp in apache1. Avoiding it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating the conditions. They only apply to the single immediately following `RewriteRule` so you need to duplicate them for both rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(?:[a-z]{2}/)?.*-p-([0-9]+)$ page.php?page_id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*) $1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make the leading slash optional (`/?`).

Comment: Negative houston, still HTTP 500. Not even "RewriteRule ^/?(?:[a-z]{2}/)?.*-p-([0-9]+)$ page.php?page_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}" alone in the .htaccess works.

Comment: @tim Do you have access to vhost/server config to turn on rewrite logging to see if the rules are being executed at all? Are you *sure* mod_rewrite is loaded in the Apache1.3 configuration? (they may be located in a different place than in Apache2)

Comment: No, unfortunately no such access. The mod rewrite is loaded because simplier rules works. Besides, shouldn't <ifmodule> prevent http 500 if it wasn't loaded?

Comment: @tim No idea what's wrong as I don't have an instance of 1.3, but you could also try removing the `%{QUERY_STRING}` from the ends, as it's redundant, use the QSA flag instead. I'll edit my answer to illustrate it.